# Processing a PCollectionTuple as a map in a ParDo function

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

So I have got a bunch of sideoutputs that I want to process together in one pipeline. This the (simplified) declaration of the tuple tags:

```
  public static final TupleTag<String> TUPLE_TAG_1 = new TupleTag<String>() {};
  public static final TupleTag<String> TUPLE_TAG_2 = new TupleTag<String>() {};
  public static final TupleTag<String> TUPLE_TAG_3 = new TupleTag<String>() {};
```

I'm using these as a side output once per ParDo iteration in the pipeline.

Currently I'm bundling them together as one PCollectionTuple:

```
PCollectionTuple metadataTags = PCollectionTuple.of(TUPLE_TAG_1, pCollectionTuple1.get(TUPLE_TAG_1))
      .and(TUPLE_TAG_2, pCollectionTuple2.get(TUPLE_TAG_2))
      .and(TUPLE_TAG_3, pCollectionTuple3.get(TUPLE_TAG_3));
```

Once all of these have been filled I'd like to process them as one Map, keyed by a TupleTag (or something else) and have written the following (again, simplified) ParDo function for them:

```
public class MyDoFn extends DoFn<Map<String, String>, MyValue> {

  @ProcessElement
  public void processContext(ProcessContext processContext) {
    Map<String, String> element = processContext.element();
    MyValue myValue = new MyValue();
    myValue.set("prop1", element.get(TUPLE_TAG_1));
    myValue.set("prop2", element.get(TUPLE_TAG_2));
    myValue.set("prop3", element.get(TUPLE_TAG_3));
    processContext.output(myValue);
  }

}
```

This is not going to work, as the `apply` function will expect a `PTransform<PCollectionTuple, OutputT>`:

```
metadataTags.apply(ParDo.of(new MyDoFn()); //Does not compile
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to join three different `PCollections`. To join them, you need to use a key over which to match different rows of each `PCollection`. Do you have a key that you can use to match the three collections?

If not, then how do you plan to *align* them together?